# Flash light issue

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am working on migrating the camera app from camera1 to camera2. I am facing a weird issue on Motorola G5 and Samsung Galaxy S4, where the flash mode is on, every time i tap on the preview view for manual focus, the flash is fired.

Did anyone run into the same issue?
Here is the code I use for tap to focus feature:

```
        val focusAreaTouch = calculateFocusArea(pointOfInterestX, pointOfInterestY, sensorArraySize)

        //cancel any existing AF trigger
        previewRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL)
        previewRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)

        try {
            captureSession?.capture(previewRequestBuilder?.build(), captureCallback, null)
        }catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Tap To Focus -> Failed to cancel any existing AF trigger.", ex)
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "AF Regions: " + previewRequestBuilder?.get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS)?.first()?.rect)

        //Then we add a new AF trigger with focus region
        previewRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, arrayOf(focusAreaTouch))

        previewRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)
        previewRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO)
        previewRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START)
```

---

Here is how I check for the AE state:

```
private fun process(result: CaptureResult) {
    when (state) {
        CameraState.STATE_LOCKING -> {
            val af = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE) ?: return
            if (af == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED
                    || af == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED
                    || af == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED) {
                val ae = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
                if (ae == null || ae == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                    state = CameraState.STATE_CAPTURING
                    onReady()
                } else {
                    state = CameraState.STATE_LOCKED
                    onPreCaptureRequired()
                }
            }
        }
        CameraState.STATE_PRECAPTURE -> {
            val ae = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
            if (ae == null || ae == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                    ae == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED ||
                    ae == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                state = CameraState.STATE_WAITING
            }
        }
        CameraState.STATE_WAITING -> {
            val ae = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
            if (ae == null || ae != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                state = CameraState.STATE_CAPTURING
                onReady()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that if you have setup AE too, then the AE algorithm will trigger the flash if it needs it to properly adjust the exposure based on the current light conditions.

To solve it, handle the flash configuration differently for the preview and photo capture sessions. Configure your **Request Builders** with the next function.

---

There are 4 places when **setFlash()** mus be called. Note that the method only sets the given builder flash configuration, you still need to pass the builder to the target session. For the preview session will be as a **Repeating Request**.

1. When initially configuring the **Preview**, with **isPreviewSession** set to **True**, so actions such as tap to focus don't trigger the Flash.
2. When taking photos, right at the point when the user presses the shutter button,
   configure the **Preview request builder** with **isPreviewSession** set
   to **False**. Setting it to **False** means this time the **Preview builder** will actually have the required target Flash configuration, so the **Capture Session Callback** knows when the Focus,
   AE, etc are converged using the target flash configuration, which
   the AE algorithm may require.
3. Then, when converged and ready to initiate the **Capture session**, call
   again **setFlash** passing the **Capture Request Builder** obtained from
   cameraDevice.**createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)**,
   again with **isPreviewSession** set to **False**.
4. Finally, when the capture has ended, in the callback that notifies
   about the capture completion, must again re-configure the **Preview request builder**
   but this time with **isPreviewSession** set to **True** so the flash
   state is set again to Off.

---

```
static final int FLASH_MODE_OFF = 0;
static final int FLASH_MODE_AUTO = 1;
static final int FLASH_MODE_ON = 2;
static final int FLASH_MODE_TORCH = 3;


public void setFlash(@NonNull final CaptureRequest.Builder builder, 
                             final boolean isPreviewSession, final int flashMode)
{
    if (isPreviewSession == true)
    {
        // For preview session

        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);

        if (flashMode == FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
        {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // For capture session

        if (flashMode == FLASH_MODE_OFF)
        {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        else if (flashMode == FLASH_MODE_AUTO)
        {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        else if (flashMode == FLASH_MODE_ON)
        {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
        else if (flashMode == FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
        {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        }
    }
}
```